# How can I make a circle segment in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

What I'm trying to achieve is something like one of these segments

[image]

There's any way to do it without rasterizing the shape?

Comment: photoshop is raster by definition, doesn't it?

Comment: It have a lot of vector features.

Comment: vector-like features you mean? i dont think it is real vectors

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop-cs6

Comment: What have you tried? What are you struggling with? There's lots and lots of ways you can make the shapes you indicated.

Comment: I was only able to do it rasterizing. I was not able to modify the circle shape (I don't even know if it's the way to do it). I'd appreciate if you show me a single way on how to do it.

Comment: @Ilan: even Illustrator has to rasterize everything in order to present it to you on your display. I think you are making a false distinction here.

Comment: I'd just draw a circle and mask the portion I did not want in Photoshop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid having to rasterize:

1. Draw an Ellipse using the Ellipse tool in "Shape drawing" mode while holding down the SHIFT key to constrain it to a circle. By default the resulting circle will have 4 segments/anchor points.
   [image]
2. Use the direct selection tool to select and delete segments to give you the desired arc.
   [image]
   [image]
3. You can always add more anchor points to the circle (Add anchor point tool) to get exactly the size arc you want by slicing up the circle into more segments.
   [image: More anchor points added]
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Circle with stroke applied:

[image]

Fill Opacity down to 0:

[image]

Rasterize effect:

[image]

Delete what you don't want, select, and make work path:

[image]

Of course this is only one method. Its probably easier to use Illustrator. Might even be easier to just use the pen tool in photoshop but to get perfect circles you'd have to set up guidelines or grids anyways so maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Ellipse tool in the toolbox to make a circle.
2. You can draw another circle inside to make a wheel (press <kbd>ALT</kbd> to substract)
3. Draw a rectangle with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to intersect the new area and the existing shapes.
4. Combine shapes

[More info](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/photoshop/using/drawing-shapes.html)