# Photoshop not giving any vector artwork

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, images, raster

Ok, I've used illustrator before and I've become very comfortable with it. It gives me smooth strokes and converts my artwork to vector.

Now, I've just started using Photoshop CS6. But I have one problem — any stroke or shape I draw in Photoshop doesn't look vector, instead it looks rasterized! I can see individual pixels.

It looks like this:

[image: raster image]

How do I make this smooth like a vector image?

Comment: You haven't asked a question but to save the time, the closest thing to a question would be "How do I make true vectors in Photoshop?" which Scott has already answered here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop-cs6 --- Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: how come they show smooth images here- https://www.udemy.com/blog/photoshop-logo-tutorial/

Comment: Stroke and anti-aliasing properties on yours probably differ.

Comment: any useful tips on how I use my anti-aliasing for the purpose of smoothing or getting the same effect like the images posted in the tutorial link I posted ...??

Comment: You gone too deep for this 600% :D

Comment: @that-kickass-girl, don't zoom in too much and you will get smooth edges.

Answer (score 3):

You can see individual pixels because you're zoomed in to 600%. Photoshop is meant for raster editing; it does not have the same zooming properties found in Illustrator. Even though you're working with vector shapes within Photoshop, it's still rasterizing them for you on your canvas.

You can still scale your vector shapes and the quality will be preserved, but zoom in far enough and you'll always see the pixels. The same goes for text in Photoshop which is inherently vector.

I advise that you create or edit your vector artwork in Illustrator. If you need to bring it into Photoshop for some sort of post processing that's fine, but Photoshop just plan and simple isn't the best tool for editing vector artwork.