# Multiple colors for different shapes under one layer (Vector) in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is it possible to give different colors for shapes that's all under one layer. Basically i am trying create a vector icon in Photoshop though I know its possible through Illustrator.
Is it possible to turn that circle shape in some other color? All needs to be in same layer and vector. I felt myself this question tricky.

Eg: [image]

Comment: Only if it's in another layer. Or depending on how you're going to use it, you could clipping mask a color layer over the the existing circle.

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but it may be: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop-cs6/17873#17873

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is seems like we can't give different colors for different shapes in a layer.

Answer (score 1):

No, It is not possible for a vector layer to have different colors for different shapes in Photoshop. Although if you want to retain the vector, you can make a smart object and place all your vector layer shapes as different layers in it.