# The exact and best canvas size when creating a logo

Tags: logo, canvas

Experts,Professionals,intermediate,Beginner! 
what is the best canvas size when creating a logo.
does not matter if it is inches,cm,pixel just give me some awesome answer and it will be great!

thankyou for your kindness and time for answering my question!

Answer (score 5):

The *best* solution is to work in a vector application where canvas size means nothing. You work at whatever is comfortable for you. Since it's vector, you can always resize as needed without any quality loss.

If you're working in a raster application, such as Photoshop (and *yes* that includes Photoshop's vector tools. [Photoshop *never creates vector files*](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop-cs6)) then you should switch to a vector-based app such as Illustrator, Inkscape, Xara, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the need.

Could be 32X32 - 600X400 - 1024X1024, etc., there is no right size.

If you are making the logo from raster elements then it should be exactly size as needed (more or less).

If it's too small or too big, re-sizing it will damage the quality.
Logo with blurred details it's not a good thing.

If you are working with vector elements then it does not matter how big the canvas is.

IMO it is better to choose Illustrator for logo making purpose.

Comment: is there any default size at least that ican follow? imean, the usual size when creating a logo?is it 1024 px by 1024?

Comment: Icon and logo are two different things.  These are examples for mobile icons : http://appicontemplate.com/