# image tracing on adobe illustrator vs photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, image-trace

what is the difference between image tracing on adobe illustrator or adobe photoshop? I wanted to  trace some of my friends photos for a gift, so I was watching some tutorials and realized some people trace on ps or ai. can someone tell me the difference?

Comment: Many who utilize Photoshop to trace an image simply don't have or know Illustrator. Or, the end goal is ultimately *still* a raster image, so using a raster editor doesn't *really* matter.

Comment: thank you for the your answer, i see it is mostly related based on preferences or knowledge.

Comment: What's your goal? To remove the background, perhaps? Or to convert a photo to a vector drawing? Could you show an example which shows the original and the expected result?

Comment: yeah my goal is convert a photo to vector drawing as a gift. to hang on so i was trying some youtube videos and try to choose similar pictures as they did use. they use oil paint filter mostly in the video. it was on photoshop.

Comment: What evidence you have that Illustrator could make the result (which is still 100% unknown for us) ? Show an example, then someone might tell the lowest effort tool to get it. Show the original AND the result. Your term "trace" seems to contain quite a different set of effects than what long time Illustrator users have used to mean with the same word.

Comment: If the goal is a *vector file* then you **can't** use Photoshop. [Photoshop is **not capable** of saving or exporting a vector *file*.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop/17873#17873) Photoshop can only save/export a *raster file* with some embedded vector data.

Comment: @Scott, not true. Assets generator can export shape layers as fully vector svg. Not sure which version it came in but I feel like it's been there like 5 years... I'ts definitely in my PS CC 2022: **1.** Make a shape layer **2.** suffix layer name with `.svg` **3.** Top menu `File > Generate > Image assets` **4.** save file as PSD and locate your fully vector svg file in the assets folder next to your PSD file. — Not saying it's useful here, but the statement is wrong.

Comment: @Joonas please read the "addendum" at the link in my comment.

Comment: @scott, the statement is still wrong, is it not? Feels weird you'd still maintain that it's not possible after adding that?

Comment: @Joonas it may be "splitting hairs" so to speak. But at its core Photoshop is *not* a vector application. While saving simple SVG is absolutely possible, there are entire ranges of designers that never use or need SVG. Stating Photoshop can save vector due to 1 single aspect would be like stating Illustrator is a raster application because you can select all then rasterize it. I think it's imperative to understand that Photoshop simply is not a vector application, just like it's not a video application, or 3D application even though you can do some of those within Photoshop.

Comment: @Joonas i think it comes down to a simple fact defining vector graphics differently. Sure you can do vector curves in photoshop. I can also do that in IE, Safafi an Firefox, does that make those vector editors? There is a lot of things that are integral to vector editing that photoshop can not do. Like having another embedded image that has different size pixels, or cut vectors at intersections etc. Anyway for me its more about sheer volume of objects that you can have. Its not terribly practical to have thousands of individual differently shaded objects in PS.

Comment: @jooja, I mean this was a stupid conversation. Scott was arguing about things nobody ever claimed. Nobody said PS is a vector application or a 3D application or any kind of application... **He claimed Photoshop can't save a fully vector file and I said you're wrong, it can.** The only real argument you can make against my claim it is that it's not possible in every single version of PS. — I mean sure you could extend that to "does it make sense?" but I don't care about that. PS can save a fully vector file and that it... That's all I'm saying...

Comment: @Joonas and it has been capable of doing that even before the svg exports. Life from the day curves were introduced. Why claim that it suddenly aquired this feature?

Comment: @joojaa, Scott is saying it can't I'm saying it can end of fucking story.

Comment: 99.9% of educated users seeking a vector file are **not** jumping to Photoshop to create it. I can pound in a nail with a screwdriver.. does that mean all screwdrivers should be seen as nail-pounding tools. The question asks which is a better app to trace things in.. Photoshop is **not** that for vectors.

Comment: @Scott, Photoshop can save fully vector files, you false information spreading idiot.

Comment: A distinction needs to be made. Otherwise you haphazardly lead new users into thinking Photoshop is suitable for all vector work - it's **not** even with svg exports. I posted that yes SVG can be saved from Photoshop. Out of myriad uses for actual vector files, svg is only one, and a rudimentary one at that. I do not understand the animus. Honestly, your comments come across as if you're a novice user who uses Photoshop but doesn't know, or want to learn, Illustrator or an *actual* vector application.

Answer (score 1):

Both are mostly the same, but the only thing is Photoshop is usually used in Raster(Pixels) Images and Illustrator is widely used for Vector-based images.

Like for example

> In `photoshop` your image will get distorted, or lose its quality when you zoom it on a large scale.

> But on the other hand, `Illustrator` works on vector-based images mostly used in print media.

Its absolutely your call to choose one. In both you can achieve the same output.

Comment: yeah I see, then its mostly based on preferences and what outcome you want. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a differing oppinion. There are huge differences between choosing the two.

You would use illustrators tool if you really want a vector image and you have a reasonably clean image to begin with.

You would essentially be forced to use photoshop as tracing software if you need to heavily modify the image before/during the operation for signal shaping, or cusrom channel picking. You probably want to then move to illustrator for final cleanup.

But its probably safe to say that if you must ask then both are probably interchangeable to you.

Comment: i followed a video on youtube, they did a png logo to vector image on photoshop. I followed the tutorial and as a result i still had pixels showing when i zoom in. And after exporting it as a svg file, I could not work on it on illustrator. I thought maybe expanding would work but it was greyed out. so how can it be possible to work on illustrator afterwards?

Comment: @yyolandi howwould i know what the video did?  But anyway try pdf, or copy paste

Comment: I agree with this answer. I would say that the final result should almost always end with Illustrator. Photoshop can be very useful in clearing up noise and cleaning up the image before moving to Illustrator.