# How to edit eps file in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, inkscape, eps

I am making logos in Inkscape for sale. I don't own Illustrator and I just purchased Photoshop, no skills with that one. I have a customer who wants to know if she can edit the logo in photoshop? I can save my Inkscape logo as eps file. How to edit it with Photoshop? I tried to open it, but that's all I can do...

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! To make the most of this site, please review our [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) and try and make sure your questions and answers fit within the structure of our stack exchange community.

Comment: I wonder why you would want your customer to be able to edit the logo you designed for them.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: no, you can not edit an EPS from a vector application directly in Photoshop.

Slightly longer and more meaningful answer: You can not directly edit the vector shapes, points, lines, or fills of an EPS file saved from a different application inside of Photoshop but you can manipulate colors and appearance using Photoshop's adjustment layers and you can add artwork (layers, type, etc.) over the EPS file.

See also [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/is-a-photoshop-eps-file-a-vector-format?rq=1) which may give you a better understanding of Photoshop's EPS handling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't need to edit vector shapes, let's say I have a vector logo saved in eps format, it has 3 objects: vector image, and text: name and tagline. I need to be able to separate this 3 thing (or ungroup) in photoshop, to move them around or make a new layout.. Is that possible or should I make that logo from scratch in Photoshop only? For the people who are asking eps file? I mean, so they can edit them in Photoshop.

Comment: @Katarina - It depends. If all 3 items are not overlapping, you could use Photoshop's selection tools and "change" the layout. If they are overlapping, you're better off editing the file with a tool that understands EPS natively.

Answer (score -3):

Ms powerpoint can do this very easily

Comment: Could you please explain how?