# How save Photoshop EPS with multiple clipping paths

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, eps

So I understand that the only way to save a text logo as Photoshop EPS WITH transparent background, is to:

1. Change the fonts to Shapes
2. Create paths from the shapes
3. Create clipping paths

This works fine when I only use one clipping path, with only one color. But here is the problem: my text logo has two different colors, so I have to use two layers, two paths and two clipping paths (if i merge it to one layer, only one color survives).

And when I save as eps, only the main/active clipping paths (this is in bold type, the other clipping path is regular) gets saved.

Is there a way around this? Or do I have to give my PSD to someone with Illustrator, to get a transparent EPS.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: From what I can tell, Photoshop's EPSs can only be created from one clipping path. If you're after a true vector EPS, editing (or re-creating) the artwork in Illustrator is probably the best option.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid of this. But could find any info online that this was actually the case. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop is only capable of designating **one** path in a file as a "clipping path".

Now that path can be a *compound path,* but it *must* be a single path.

While **logos** generally aren't great to create with Photoshop (a raster-based application), there may be a way to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish. However, without more detailed information it is difficult to state how exactly.

Also be aware a Photoshop EPS *can* contain vector data, but it is **not** a vector file. See here: [Is a Photoshop EPS file a vector format?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/is-a-photoshop-eps-file-a-vector-format)

The EPS format is merely a "wrapper" and can contain 100% raster data, 100% vector data, or a mix of the two. With Photoshop you can **only** ever get a mix of the two and **never** 100% vector data.

---

Sidebar... For clarity: If *placing* a Photoshop file with multiple paths into Adobe InDesign, it *is* possible to choose different paths to act as a clipping path. However the *Photoshop application itself* can only designate one path as a "clipping path" within the file.

Comment: Okay, I'll guess I have to give Illustrator a shot... or ask a friend for help. Either way - great answer! Thanks a bunch!